# File input problems - Limit number of selected files 

Tags: php, html, file-upload, limit

I'm putting two questions in this "Question"...

1) First of all, I have a `<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" />`, Now I can select as many images as I want, but I need to limit this number to 10 maximally. How would I do this?

2) What would my upload.php file look like to handle multiple uploaded images? I never had the chance to work on anything more than single image uploading, but now I'm stuck at this and I need this. I'm quite confused...

Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 You could use javascript to detect the number of files selected, and give a warning if it's more than 10

```
$('fileinput').onchange=function(){if(this.files.length>10)alert('to many files')}
//prevent submitting if to many
$('form').onsubmit=function(){if(this.files.length>10)return false;}
```

you could even check if the combined filesize isn't to big by adding up all .files[i].fileSize

2 see: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php
(short version; use: $_FILES['userfile']['name'][0], $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][0], $_FILES['userfile']['size'][0], and $_FILES['userfile']['type'][0])

Comment: `fileSize` has been deprecated, so use `.files[i].size` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[**I have already given an answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813556/count-and-limit-the-number-of-files-uploaded-html-file-input)

so i am writing only the code part here

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0]))
{
     //checking whether a single file uploaded or not
     //if enters here means no file uploaded
}
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'][10]))
{
     //checking whether 11 files uploaded or not
     //so here you can restrict user from uploading more than 10 files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the front-end, you should also consider using file upload libraries: they allow limiting and much more:

- [FineUploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader). [Demo](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html#list-number)
- [bluimp's jQuery File Upload Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). Usage: [jquery file upload restricting number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011200/jquery-file-upload-restricting-number-of-files)

They are also available at https://cdnjs.com/