# How to limit the maximum files chosen when using multiple file input

Tags: javascript, html, file

When using `<input type="file" multiple>` it's possible for the user to choose multiple files.

How does ones sets a limit for how many files can be chosen, for instance two?

Comment: This might be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813556/multiple-file-upload-file-input-limit-number-of-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count and limit the number of files uploaded (HTML file input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813556/count-and-limit-the-number-of-files-uploaded-html-file-input)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You could run some jQuery client-side validation to check:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>2){
         alert("You can only upload a maximum of 2 files");
        }
    });    
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/u4NuH/

But remember to check on the server side too as client-side validation can be bypassed quite easily.

Comment: I don't really understand why this code is marked as correct answer. It does indeed checks the number of uploaded files however does not disable form submit. jsfiddle code does not have form tag with defined action attribute and it might seem it works fine, however if we extend it by adding form tag it's going to submit the form anyway right after alert appears.

Comment: @David Mostly because people copy and paste stuff all over the place. That and it's been 6 years.

Answer (score 27):

On change of the input track how many files are selected:

```js
$("#image").on("change", function() {
    if ($("#image")[0].files.length > 2) {
        alert("You can select only 2 images");
    } else {
        $("#imageUploadForm").submit();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>On change of the input track how many files are selected:</strong>
<input name="image[]" id="image" type="file"  multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg" >
```

Answer (score 12):

This should work and protect your form from being submitted if the number of files is greater then `max_file_number`.

```js
$(function() {

  var // Define maximum number of files.
      max_file_number = 3,
      // Define your form id or class or just tag.
      $form = $('form'),
      // Define your upload field class or id or tag.
      $file_upload = $('#image_upload', $form),
      // Define your submit class or id or tag.
      $button = $('.submit', $form);

  // Disable submit button on page ready.
  $button.prop('disabled', 'disabled');

  $file_upload.on('change', function () {
    var number_of_images = $(this)[0].files.length;
    if (number_of_images > max_file_number) {
      alert(`You can upload maximum ${max_file_number} files.`);
      $(this).val('');
      $button.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $button.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The only simple solution that works, of this entire question. Awesome!

Answer (score 10):

Another possible solution with JS

```
function onSelect(e) {
    if (e.files.length > 5) {
        alert("Only 5 files accepted.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: on chrome onselect does not fire the method. onchange does fire but it does not prevent default.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can do something like this

```
<input
  ref="fileInput"
  multiple
  type="file"
  style="display: none"
  @change="trySubmitFile"
>
```

and the function can be something like this.

```
trySubmitFile(e) {
  if (this.disabled) return;
  const files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  if (files.length > 5) {
    alert('You are only allowed to upload a maximum of 2 files at a time');
  }
  if (!files.length) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(files.length, 2); i++) {
    this.fileCallback(files[i]);
  }
}
```

I am also searching for a solution where this can be limited at the time of selecting files but until now I could not find anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider using libraries to do that: they allow limiting and much more:

- [FineUploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader). [Demo](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html#list-number) using `validation.itemLimit` as of 5.16.2:

  ```
  var restrictedUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
      validation: {
          itemLimit: 3,
      }
  });
  ```
- [bluimp's jQuery File Upload Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). Usage: [jquery file upload restricting number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011200/jquery-file-upload-restricting-number-of-files) using `maxNumberOfFiles` as of v9.22.0:

  ```
  $('#fileuploadbasic').fileupload({
    maxNumberOfFiles: 6
  });
  ```

They are also available at https://cdnjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, where I am sending image through input type file.
The form is submitted separately through axios on onSubmit event of form, so I am using FormData web api to send form contents as multipart/form data.

In case of handling image count, under the condition where name is equal to images, we alert the message and also set the value to empty array.
Still on the UI, it will show the count of images slected so, we write the messsage clear, your images won't be sent.

Here is the properties I have given to the file input field, as a part of JS object. As I am looping through an array to populate input fields.

```
 {
  name: "images",
  type: "file",
  accept: "image/*",
  multiple: true,
},
```

And down here is the code where I have handled OnChange and Onsubmit

```
    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    let { checked, name, value } = e.target;
    if (name === "status") {
      value = checked ? "active" : "inactive";
    }
    if (name === "images") {



      value = [...e.target.files];
      if (value.length > 5) {
        value = [];
        alert("Can select only upto 5 images, your images won't be sent");
      }
    }
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
  };
  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form);

    // set data with formDataApi
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const key in form) {
      formData.append(key, form[key]);
    }
    dispatch(postProductsAction(formData));
  };
```

Answer (score -5):

Use two `<input type=file>` elements instead, without the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: this will only allow one image, he wants 2 images

Comment: no, this allows for two separate filelist objects and was consistently used as THE method for both uploading multiple files and limiting their numbers---15 years ago

Comment: If the requirement is really just "have two different single inputs", then this is actually the best answer @Diego. The question being sadly so unclear, we can't really say.

Comment: @me_ I'm really curious as to what the solution is now. Hopefully you're not talking about that jQuery cluster over there. That was like, totally rad seven years ago.

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier the multiple attribute didn't exist until html 5...  regardless of using a library or just plain javascript, the number of files must be checked after files are chosen.  I'd say the solution is tell the user no more than a given number of files, and then check file type and number when the popup closes...  reject the files object if it exceeds the given number and start again.  But no, this is not the best solution--interms of ui alone it is much slower...  we have the multiple attribute now, use it.

Answer (score -8):

if you want php you can count the array and just make an if statement
like

```
if((int)count($_FILES['i_dont_know_whats_coming_next'] > 2)
      echo "error message";
```