# Allow multiple files to be uploaded

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I have a script I found online that I modified a little. I'd like to allow five files to be uploaded at one. Here is my script:

```
// Folder to upload files to. Must end with slash /
define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','../uploads/');

// Maximum allowed file size, Kb
// Set to zero to allow any size
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10240);

// Upload success URL. User will be redirected to this page after upload.
define('SUCCESS_URL','my info');

// Allowed file extensions. Will only allow these extensions if not empty.
// Example: $exts = array('avi','mov','doc');
$exts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

// rename file after upload? false - leave original, true - rename to some unique         filename
define('RENAME_FILE', true);

// put a string to append to the uploaded file name (after extension);
// this will reduce the risk of being hacked by uploading potentially unsafe files;
// sample strings: aaa, my, etc.
define('APPEND_STRING', '');

// Need uploads log? Logs would be saved in the MySql database.
define('DO_LOG', true);

// MySql data (in case you want to save uploads log)
define('DB_HOST','my info'); // host, usually localhost
define('DB_DATABASE','my info'); // database name
define('DB_USERNAME','my info'); // username
define('DB_PASSWORD','my info'); // password


/*CREATE TABLE uploads_log (
  log_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  log_filename varchar(128) default '',
  log_size int(10) default 0,
  log_ip varchar(24) default '',
  log_date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY  (log_id),
 KEY (log_filename)
);*/



####################################################################
###  END OF SETTINGS.   DO NOT CHANGE BELOW
####################################################################

// Allow script to work long enough to upload big files (in seconds, 2 days by default)
@set_time_limit(172800);

// following may need to be uncommented in case of problems
// ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","10800");

function showUploadForm($message='') {
  $max_file_size_tag = '';
  if (MAX_FILE_SIZE > 0) {
    // convert to bytes
    $max_file_size_tag = "<input name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='".(MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024)."'         type='hidden' >\n";
  }

  // Load form template
  include ('index.php');
}

// errors list
$errors = array();

$message = '';

// we should not exceed php.ini max file size
$ini_maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
if (!is_numeric($ini_maxsize)) {
  if (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'M') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024*1024;
  elseif (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'K') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024;
  elseif (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'G') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024*1024*1024;
}
if ($ini_maxsize < MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024) {
  $errors[] = "Alert! Maximum upload file size in php.ini (upload_max_filesize) is less         than script's MAX_FILE_SIZE";
}

// show upload form
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  showUploadForm(join('',$errors));
}

// process file upload
else {

  while(true) {

    // make sure destination folder exists
    if (!@file_exists(DESTINATION_FOLDER)) {
      $errors[] = "Destination folder does not exist or no permissions to see it.";
      break;
    }

    // check for upload errors
    $error_code = $_FILES['filename']['error'];
    if ($error_code != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      switch($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
          // uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
          $errors[] = "File is too big (1).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
          // uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in         the HTML form
          $errors[] = "File is too big (2).";
          break;
         case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
          // uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (1).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
          // No file was uploaded
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (2).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
          // Missing a temporary folder
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (3).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
          // Failed to write file to disk
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (4).";
          break;
        case 8:
          // File upload stopped by extension
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (5).";
          break;
      } // switch

      // leave the while loop
      break;
    }

    // get file name (not including path)
    $filename = @basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);

    // filename of temp uploaded file
    $tmp_filename = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

    $file_ext = @strtolower(@strrchr($filename,"."));
    if (@strpos($file_ext,'.') === false) { // no dot? strange
      $errors[] = "Suspicious file name or could not determine file extension.";
      break;
    }
    $file_ext = @substr($file_ext, 1); // remove dot

    // check file type if needed
    if (count($exts)) {   /// some day maybe check also $_FILES['user_file']['type']
      if (!@in_array($file_ext, $exts)) {
        $errors[] = "Files of this type are not allowed for upload.";
        break;
      }
    }

    // destination filename, rename if set to
    $dest_filename = $filename;
    if (RENAME_FILE) {
      $dest_filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . $file_ext;
    }
    // append predefined string for safety
    $dest_filename = $dest_filename . APPEND_STRING;

    // get size
    $filesize = intval($_FILES["filename"]["size"]); // filesize($tmp_filename);

    // make sure file size is ok
   if (MAX_FILE_SIZE > 0 && MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024 < $filesize) {
      $errors[] = "File is too big (3).";
      break;
    }

    if (!@move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename , DESTINATION_FOLDER . $dest_filename)) {
      $errors[] = "Could not upload file (6).";
      break;
    }

    if (DO_LOG) {
      // Establish DB connection
      $link = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
      if (!$link) {
        $errors[] = "Could not connect to mysql.";
        break;
      }
      $res = @mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link);
      if (!$res) {
        $errors[] = "Could not select database.";
        break;
      }
      /*$m_ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
     $m_size = $filesize;
      $m_fname = mysql_real_escape_string($dest_filename);
      $sql = "insert into _uploads_log (log_filename,log_size,log_ip) values         ('$m_fname','$m_size','$m_ip')";
      $res = @mysql_query($sql);
      if (!$res) {
        $errors[] = "Could not run query.";
        break;
      }*/
      @mysql_free_result($res);
      @mysql_close($link);
    } // if (DO_LOG)


   // redirect to upload success url
    header('Location: ' . SUCCESS_URL);
    die();

    break;

  } // while(true)

  // Errors. Show upload form.
  $message = join('',$errors);
  showUploadForm($message);

}

?>
```

and my html form looks like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file-upload.php">
    <div><?php echo $message; ?></div><?php echo $max_file_size_tag; ?>
        Please select file to upload:     <input multiple type="file" size="20" name="filename">
     <input type="submit" multiple value="Upload" name="submit">
     <label style="display:block;position:absolute;left:-9999px">
    Are you a bot?
<input type=checkbox name=honeypot value=1>
    </label>
</form>
```

Like I said, I only want to allow 5 files to be uploaded at one so that the total size of the upload doesn't exceed 10 mb's. Thank you in advance!

Comment: First in HTML every attribute's value needs to be surrounded by " . Second your code is a giant mess of bad maintable code. All the @ before functions suppress errors which is not good at all. It is just stupid to assume that no error will occur.

As your code is so big it is very difficult to actually find a possible problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two options here.

1. Setting the limit on client side
        By clicking the upload button you can call a JavaScript function and check the number of files are greater than 5, then show an alert message and stops the post function.
   Visit [How to limit maximum items on a multiple input (<input type="file" multiple />)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-maximum-items-on-a-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple)
2. Setting the limit on server side (PHP script)
        Your current script will upload only one file even if you are selecting multiple files. In order to handle multiple uploads you have to loop the `$_FILES` array through a `foreach` loop. And add a counter inside the foreach loop to process the first five files
   Visit http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php