# attribute min and max in input file Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm trying to create a multiple uploads with ZF2. I would set the min and max attribute on the input file. I tried in every way but ZF2 ignores these 2 attributes for the input file.

How can I do?

```
namespace Admin\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class Image extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('image');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'image',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\File',
            'attributes' => array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'accept' => '.jpg,.png',
                'id' => 'image',
                'min' => 1,
                'max' => 5,
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'save',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'class' => 'btn btn-success'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: at least post what you have tried..

Comment: sorry you're right, I added the code.

Comment: Are you trying to add a filesize min/max for the upload?

Comment: No, min and max I need to select the files. If the max attribute is equal to 3, the user can only upload 3 files. The input has the multiple attribute of html 5.

Comment: I think you're not even close to that :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-maximum-items-on-a-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple