# HTML limit files selected when the user tries to upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type='file' id="uploadImg" name="image[]" accept="image/jpeg" multiple="multiple"/>
```

I have an input file multiple, I want to limit max-10 files. Is any way to limit user can only select 10 files when their upload window pop?

(I'm not asking about detecting and giving alert, I'm asking about limit files a user can select.)

Maybe something like `<input type='file' limit='10' />`?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-maximum-items-on-a-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this with jQuery adding an `onchange` event that checks `this.files.length` in the callback

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/ArTD4/

Answer (score 0):

Try

[Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

```
$(function () { // wait for document to load
    $('#MyFileUpload').MultiFile(10); //limit will be set to 10
});
```

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/