# Select limited file in input type file in open popup

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to select the limited file from the open input type file popup.
I don't want to used validation like jquery or javascript.

```
<input type="file" name="question_pic" id="id_question_pic" max-uploads = 6/>
```

Comment: You're missing the `multiple` property. And I don't think you can do it without JS and if you re-consider, there's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-maximum-items-on-a-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple) that might help your through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to limit the no. of files upload:

> HTML

```
<input type="file" name="question_pic" id="id_question_pic" multiple max-uploads = 6/>
```

> Jquery

```
var noOfUploads;
$("#id_question_pic").change(function() {
    if(noOfUploads > $(this).attr(max-uploads))
    {
    alert('Only '+$(this).attr(max-uploads)+' uploads Allowed');
    }
    else
    {
    noOfUploads = noOfUploads + 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: **`I don't want to used validation like jquery or javascript.`**

Comment: Without Jquery or Javascript limiting number of files is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to do client-side validation and tagged your question with PHP, you must do it **server-side**. But then, remind that you'll only have answer to your request once the HTTP REQUEST is complete (after uploading the files to transfer).

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="question_pic[]" id="id_question_pic" multiple>
```

**PHP**

```
if (count($_REQUEST['question_pic']) > 6) {
    echo "You can't upload more than 6 files";
    // other error dealing code
} else {
    echo "Upload ok!";
    // other after-upload dealing code
}
```

**OBS:** there is no HTML5 native property for `input type=file` named `max-uploads`.

**OBS2:** if you don't want to do it server-side neither, then there is no way.