# Is there any way to define maximum amount of files, that can be selected via file input?

Tags: html, forms, file, input

I was trying to find a html way to define maximum amount of files that can be selected by the input like this:

```
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="images[]">{{t('label.images')}}</label>
    <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
    <p class="right-infobox">{{t('label.images-info')}}</p>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm using Laravel, but this does not matter in this case.
The problem is, user can select as many images as he wants.

I would like to define it on the client side somehow without JavaScript. If I don't prevent it, this will eat my traffic with no reason and I will get rid of rest images anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to limit maximum items on a multiple input (<input type="file" multiple />)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-maximum-items-on-a-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple)

Comment: You can not define file size in html form you can check it using javascript if you want

Comment: well, so there is no way in pure html? I know i can use jQuery or JS, but that was not the question.

Comment: If you truly want to limit the user to `n` files, you could just provide a UI with `n` file inputs. It's not ideal in terms of user experience but may be the only HTML-only way. However, I would recommend just using JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to provide one input field for the users instead of 5, it just looks better and it's more user-friendly. Sad there is no way in pure HTML, I will workaround it with JavaScript, because it must be blocked. Thanks

Comment: Blocking with javascript is not very useful if it really "*must be blocked*". You must guard your server as well.

Comment: Yeah Im aware of that... But this will save at least some traffic