# How to upload multiple images but limit them to 12 (via smartphone)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, smartphone

I am currently using a cool cropping plugin called [cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/). I want to upload multiple images at once via `<input type="file" multiple/>`, crop them and save them at once.

My aim is to have the possibility to upload images from a smartphone, since it isn't quite user friendly to upload every image separately. But! I want to limit the image selection to 12 images. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: You cant avoid selecting more than 12, but you can simply check how many of them are selected and warn the user etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit maximum items on a multiple input (<input type="file" multiple />)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-maximum-items-on-a-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple)

Answer (score 0):

Try this this is simple to understand and apply. here you are just checking if there is 13th file selected then you get your if block to do code.

```js
$("#abc").change (function(){
  if(this.files[12]){
    alert('not allowed!');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" multiple id="abc">
```