# how to limit the maximum number of uploaded image files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit the maximum upload of image files by adding alerts to the following `code`

the alert is `alert("You Have Reached The MAXIMUM Upload Limit");`
so when I add one by one to the specified limit, an `alert` will appear

```
<div class="files col-sm-4" id="files1">
    <input type="file" name="files1" id="imagesix" multiple />
    <br />Selected files:
    <ol class="fileList"></ol>
</div>
```

script

```
$.fn.fileUploader = function (filesToUpload) {
    this.closest(".files").change(function (evt) {

        for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
            filesToUpload.push(evt.target.files[i]);
        };
        var output = [];

        for (var i = 0, f; f = evt.target.files[i]; i++) {
            var removeLink = "<i class=\"fa fa-times fa-close removeFile\" href=\"#\" data-fileid=\"" + i + "\"></i>";

            output.push("<li><strong>", escape(f.name), "</strong> ", removeLink, " </li> ");
        }

        $(this).children(".fileList")
            .append(output.join(""));
    });
};

var filesToUpload = [];

$(document).on("click",".removeFile", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fileName = $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
    for(i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++ i){
        if(filesToUpload[i].name == fileName){
            filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
        }   
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
});


$("#files1").fileUploader(filesToUpload);
```

Answer (score 1):

this code I implement for my project but as per your requirement you can change it.

> refrence: [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-the-maximum-files-chosen-when-using-multiple-file-input?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
    var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
    if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>2){
     alert("You can only upload a maximum of 2 files");
    }
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) plugin for the same. It allows you to configure it as per the need.