# How to limit the maximum files chosen when using multiple file input in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to limit the maximum upload of files while choosing a file in ReactJS.
I'm not sure how to handle this. I tried with some solution but it did not work for me.

```
<input name="eventUpload" type="file" onChange={this.uploadMultipleFiles} multiple className="form-control-file" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-the-maximum-files-chosen-when-using-multiple-file-input

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with some simple Javascript conditional check.

```
const MAX_LENGTH = 3;

uploadMultipleFiles = (e) => {
  if (Array.from(e.target.files).length > MAX_LENGTH) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(`Cannot upload files more than ${MAX_LENGTH}`);
    return;
  }
}
```