# How to.limit a users conten upload in django

Tags: python, django, backend, web-deployment, flash-message

Hello guys I want to restrict user, my I am working on a project in django where I have a producer model so I want to restrict the producer from uploading contents based on the particular package they're currently running on...

Let's say if they subscribe to a pro package they can't upload more that 5 contents..

Comment: check if this helps  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62960258/8401179

Comment: **PS:** I removed the Adobe `Flash` tag since this question is not about the discontinued plugin. I assume at best, you want `flash-message` which is like notifications or  pop-ups??? Are you asking how to restrict **number of selected items** in file browser when a user clicks your "Upload" button?