# How to set a maximum amount of file selections when a user is uploading files via an input on a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to set a max limit on an input of files when uploading files to a blob container.
The code below allows for multiple selections of files and I want to limit it to a maximum of 5 is that possible ?

```
<input multiple type="file" name="files" id="files" required />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>2){
         alert("You can only upload a maximum of 2 files");
        }
    });    
});​
```

[How to limit the maximum files chosen when using multiple file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-the-maximum-files-chosen-when-using-multiple-file-input)