# HTML sanitization, limit amount of images

Tags: html, image, html-sanitizing

In recieiving html input from a user(rich text editor) , I would like to limit the amount of images they have submitted. Is there a way to allow the first few images and then remove the rest?

The images are in the form

```
  <img src="">
```

Comment: Please Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813556/count-and-limit-the-number-of-files-uploaded-html-file-input

Comment: @Jatin, thanks for that link. Flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Oh I should clarify, I'm not allowing users to upload pictures. They are in the form <img src="">, the other post doesn't help me. Please re open the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to do this server side, use the HTMLAgilityPack.
You can give it the HTML content and query this, in your case you'd want a list of all html images.
Using this list, you could verify the count, remove elements etc.
Example(using links, not images in this sample of code):

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 TextReader TR= new StringReader(SomeText);
 doc.Load(TR);
 HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use that to verify the number of plaintext characters as well?

Comment: Oh also, do you know how to limit the number of new lines?

Comment: For plain text, I would use regex to remove all HTML, then get the length of the string.Something like : Regex.Replace(SomeString, "<.*?>", String.Empty);