# ActiveStorage rails : limit the number of files uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I want to limit user to select up to 2 files (in the input tag ?).

```
 <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
```

I would like to limit user to select up to 2 files (front and backoffice).

Is there a way (preferable a hard coded option) to limit the number of files that user can select?

Comment: This is really not a Rails issue if you're thinking about limiting it in the UI, all the `file_field` does is just spit out some `input type='file'` html tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-the-maximum-files-chosen-when-using-multiple-file-input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count and limit the number of files uploaded (HTML file input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813556/count-and-limit-the-number-of-files-uploaded-html-file-input)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a limit. Javascript can detect the number of files or your Ruby backend can detect the number of files, but you have to do validation outside the HTML.

If you have a small, hardcoded, number of file fields, you can always create a unique `form_field` for each and force the user to update each one separately and then submit them in an array to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Behind the scenes Rails is just generating markup. Per the source code at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1ce5153a099e82f761315154dfe5e01253dafd81/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1202

```
#   file_field(:post, :image, multiple: true)
#   # => <input type="file" id="post_image" name="post[image][]" multiple="multiple" />
```

Rails is just setting the `multiple` attribute to `"multiple"`. You might be able to achieve what you're after with JavaScript. You could also just output two file upload inputs without the multiple attribute...