# jquery file upload restricting number of files

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload to upload the files to the server . I want to restrict the user to upload maximum 6 files . I search the wiki jquery file upload but didnt find the parameter for it . Is there any way that i can restrict the user on number of uplaods

Comment: which jquery plugin you are using? generally inside callback function it will hold those files in some sort of json array whose size you can put in if() clause

Comment: A why not working version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347805/jquery-multiple-file-upload-limit-number-of-files-not-working

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `maxNumberOfFiles` here is [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#maxnumberoffiles) :

```
$('#fileuploadbasic').fileupload({

maxNumberOfFiles: 6

});
```

Comment: This does not work in my case. I can select more than 6 files and it also uploads all selected files.

Comment: I found that sometimes the browser caches the .js file.
Try refreshing the actual .js page and see if the changes take effect then.

Comment: This answer should be removed or at least clarified. Its no longer correct. That maxNumberOfFiles option only works if youre using the jquery fileupload with the pre-made UI. Otherwise you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 19):

**maxNumberOfFiles** was not working for me so i did the following

```
$('#fileuploadbasic').fileupload({
    change : function (e, data) {
        if(data.files.length>=5){
            alert("Max 5 files are allowed")
            return false;
        }
    },
    maxFileSize: 20000000,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/i,
});
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed.

Comment: I can't edit the answer for some reason, but if you replace the "change" handler by "submit", it will work. That did the trick for me and "change" wasn't working either :)

Comment: @naturalBornCamper above code is for the time when we select file. it check the file before submitting.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the uploading files by the "Uploadhandler.php" file .change the "max_number_of_files" option. works for me. But it only validates when you upload the file.

Comment: This is valid.  A lot of the settings are available client side (via js) and server side (via PHP).  I found it useful to duplicate on both, so that the user gets client feedback before the file has been uploaded, but a more secure level of validation takes place on the server also.

Comment: Just remember to have some place to show this limit. In my case 100 uploads worked and the others failed, with no error message, just "An error ocurred".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "Krajee" fileupload, then you will have to use

```
$('#fileuploadbasic').fileinput({
    maxFileCount: 6
});
```

If set to 0, it means size allowed is unlimited. Defaults to 0.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
$('#fileuploadbasic').fileupload({
  //.....
  paramName: 'your_input_name',
  add : function (e, data) {
    if(data.paramName != undefined) data.submit();
  }
});
```